# How to use MPTT for django to get all children?

Tags: django, mptt

I'm trying to get all the children of a category:

```
def list_sub(self, category_name):
   # this will return the parent if exists
   category = Category.objects.filter(seo_title__exact = seo_title).filter(lang__exact = 'pt-PT').filter(level__exact = 1)

   if category:
      # but this doesn't work and in the documentation there are no examples
      # of how to get it. See link about the method
      sub_categories = category.get_children()
```

http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/models.html#get-children

### Update1:

```
qc = Category.objects.filter(seo_title__exact = cat).filter(lang__exact = 'pt-PT').filter(level__exact = 1)
category = qc.get()

if category:
    qsc = category.get_children()
    sub_categories = qsc.get()
```

now I get this error: "get() returned more than one Category -- it returned 7! Lookup parameters were {}"

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is not with MPTT. The issue is that `category` is a queryset, not an instance - `get_children()` is an model method, not a queryset method.

Use `get` instead of `filter`.

Comment: thanks! now I've done it. but I get this other error.. "get() returned more than one Category -- it returned 7! Lookup parameters were {}" what does that means. EDIT: ok.. I have to use all()