# Django- How to get mptt children in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-mptt

The closest thing that I could find to my questions is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048452/how-to-use-mptt-for-django-to-get-all-children).

I have the following model:

```
class Specialty(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Specialties'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Specialty_Category_Map(models.Model):
    specialty = models.ForeignKey(Specialty, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'parent__name':'rotation'})
```

I have the following in my views:

```
def viewSpecAndRot(request):
    specialties = Specialty.objects.all
    rotations = Specialty_Category_Map.objects.all
    return render(request, 'view_spec_rot.html', {'specialties': specialties, 'rotations': rotations, }, )
```

Lastly, Here is part of the template:

```
{% for specialty in specialties %}
        <h3><a data-toggle="pill" href="#" class="">{{specialty}}</a></h3>
        <div>
            {% for rotation in rotations %}
                {% ifequal specialty rotation.specialty %}
                        <li class="list-group-item ">{{rotation.category}}</li>
                {% endifequal %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

This would all work well under normal circumstances, but I have a few subcategories of the rotations themselves like the following:

```
rotation
---something
------something_low
---------something_lower
```

How would I access the lower 2 children in the template? I have already looked into using [recursetree](https://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/templates.html)  on each `rotation.category` but to no avail.

Comment: You want the tree structure of category?

Comment: @MicroPyramid Sorry for the delay, but yes using the mapping model.